# Игра на Java не проходит компиляцию

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

public class GuessGame {
    Player p1;
    Player p2;
    Player p3;

    public void startGame() {
        p1 = new Player();
        p2 = new Player();
        p3 = new Player();

        int guessp1 = 0;
        int guessp2 = 0;
        int guessp3 = 0;

        boolean p1isRight = false;
        boolean p2isRight = false;
        boolean p3isRight = false;

        int targetNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println("Я загадываю число от 0 до 9...");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Число, которое нужно угадать, -" + targetNumber);

            p1.guess();
            p2.guess();
            p3.guess();

            guessp1 = p1.number;
            System.out.println("Первый игрок думает, что это" + guessp1);

            guessp2 = p2.number;
            System.out.println("Первый игрок думает, что это" + guessp2);

            guessp3 = p3.number;
            System.out.println("Первый игрок думает, что это" + guessp3);

            if (guessp1 == targetNumber) {
                p1isRight = true;
            }

            if (guessp2 == targetNumber) {
                p2isRight = true;
            }

            if (guessp3 == targetNumber) {
                p3isRight = true;
            }

            if (p1isRight || p2isRight || p3isRight) {
                System.out.println("У нас есть победитель!");
                System.out.println("Первый игрок угадал?" + p1isRight);
                System.out.println("Второй игрок угадал?" + p2isRight);
                System.out.println("Третий игрок угадал?" + p3isRight);
                System.out.println("Конец игры");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Игроки должны попробовать ещё раз!");
            }
        }
    }
    public class Player {
        int number = 0;
        public void guess() {
            number = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            System.out.println("Думаю, что это число " + number);
        }
    }

    public class GameLauncher {
        public static void main (String[] args) {
            GuessGame game = new GuessGame();
            game.startGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Такие вот дела. Ругается на последний кусок кода, запускающий игровой процесс

```
public class GameLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        GuessGame game = new GuessGame();
        game.startGame();
    }
}
```

А именно на **static**. Подскажите пожалуйста как нужно правильно это дело оформить((([image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам не нужен внутренний класс GameLauncher

Comment: Если вы уж делаете открытый класс внутри класса, то делайте его статичным `public static class GameLauncher`. Ну и хорошо придерживаться правила 1 Класс - 1 Файл

Comment: @AlexanderChernin@ArchDemon  Спасибо огромное, я и не понял сразу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В не статических вложенных классах не допускаются статические методы.